# How to determine each point of a circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a circle with a predefined radius (e.g r=5), so X(+/-)max and Y(+/-)max equals (+/-)5.
How do I determine all other points of the circle with a function?
For example: How do I get the +Y/-Y Value for X=2,5?

Thank you :)

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations

Answer (score 1):

Well the general equation of that circle is $$x^2+y^2=5^2\tag 1$$
If the centre is not the origin but instead $(a, b)$, the equation would be $$(x-a) ^2+(y-b)^2=25$$

In this case the centre is the origin, so we rearrange $(1)$ to:
$$y^2=25-x^2=25-\frac52^2=\frac{75}{4}\implies y=\pm\frac{\sqrt{75}}{2}=\pm \frac52 \sqrt 3$$